# How to submit one Form with jQuery bind-submit if i have multiple forms on page?

Tags: jquery, submit, bind, forms, http-post

I am binding jQuery's submit function to the form-Tag. This works fine with one Form, but if I have more than one Form, it submits Data from all Forms in the Post variable.

How can I submit only one Form?

```
$('form').bind('submit',function() {
    var data = $('form').serializeAnything();
    $.post('forms/form.ajax.submit.php',data,function(response) {
        ...
});
```

Comment: You need to customize your selector : $('form'). Try to set an ID to the form, and then use $('form#ID'), or a more complex CSS selector (:first-child, etc)

Answer (score 3):

Use IDs for your forms and use that for data variable.

```
var data = $('#this_form').serializeAnything();
```

or traverse by find the parent form like `$(this).closest('form').serializeAnything();`

Answer (score 0):

```
var data;
data=$('form1').serializeAnything();
data+=$('form2').serializeAnything();
data+=$('form3').serializeAnything();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using selectors id or class.

e.g.

var data = $( '#formID' ).serializeAnything();

var data = $( '.formCLASS' ).serializeAnything();

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$('form').serializeAnything();` you want `$(this).serializeAnything();` (or, perhaps, `$(this).serialize();` if jQuery's standard serialization function will do).

```
/* attach a submit handler to each form */
$('form').submit(function (event) {

    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();

    /* get some values from elements on the page: */
    var $form = $(this),
        form_data = $form.serialize(),
        url = $form.attr('action');

    /* Send the data using post */
    var posting = $.post(url, form_data);
    console.log('finished ajax post');

    /* Put the results in a div */
    posting.done(function (data) {
        console.log('now load response');
        $('#result').empty().append( $(data) );
    });
});
```

See [a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/QjaTq/29/](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/QjaTq/29/).

Comment: Code taken from answers to "jQuery submit/preventDefault/post" http://stackoverflow.com/q/17242767/1430996